# Width of multiline React-Native Text component won't resize to length of longest line of text on Android

Tags: android, flexbox, react-native, react-native-flexbox

I have a multiline React-Native Text component whose width should auto-adjust to the width of the longest line of text. This is working on iOS but not on Android, and I'm not sure why.

Please see [this expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@blumaterial/wrapped-multiline-text-issue) for a demo.
on iOS it looks like this:

[image]

on Android it looks like this:

[image]

The demo above is just a stripped down excerpt from the full app. I need to keep `flexDirection: 'row'` because in the full app there are other items I need to display to the right of this textbox.

Comment: In your text resource, do you have a line break after 'Indubitably.'? What exactly do you mean by 'width of the longest line of text.'?

Comment: No line breaks in that string at all. By "width of the longest line of text" I mean that the text box should be no longer than the end of "Indubitably." - basically no wider than it needs to be to encapsulate all of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of useState, try using a string variable with a linebreak:

```
const TextInANest = () => {
  var bodyText = "This is not really a bird nest. Nope. Indubitably.\n Antagonistic."
   // const bodyText = useState("This is not really a bird nest. Nope. Indubitably. Antagonistic.");
```

This way, you will get the same result on Android and iOS. It's more like a workaround than a solution but hope its helpful, still.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a lot of these text boxes and the text strings are variable so I can't manually line break every single one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the same but didn't find anything. I tried some "flex" solutions but it didn't work. Finally I've written "react" solution and it works (TypeScript):

```
const [maxLineWidth, setMaxLineWidth] = useState<number>()
const onTextLayout = useCallback((event: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextLayoutEventData>) => {
    const nextMaxLineWidth = event.nativeEvent.lines.reduce((result, line) => Math.max(result, line.width), 0)
    setMaxLineWidth(Math.ceil(nextMaxLineWidth))
}, [])
// ...
<Text
    style={{ width: maxLineWidth }}
    onTextLayout={onTextLayout}
>
    Very very long text!!!
</Text>
```

Comment: I tried this but it resulted in an infinite loop, continuously resizing the text field.. RN 0.63 in case it matters.